# A single thread to which you can subscribe methods, to be executed in an unordered fashion

Tags: c#, multithreading, methods, delegates

I need the following logic implemented:

1. a thread to which you can subscribe/unsubscribe methods at runtime.
2. It's fine for all these methods to have an header such as (Object sender, EventArgs e) and to return void.
3. These methods scope must be the scope of the class where they are defined *lexically*.
4. There's no guarantee about the order of execution

I've come up with the following implementation, which seems to do exactly what I need: basically I start an internal thread which triggers an event each x milliseconds. You can subscribe/unsubscribe delegates to this event through appropriate methods.

Before sticking to it I'd like to know if there may be subtle issues following this approach.

```
public class Orchestrator
{
    private Thread _mainThread;

    private event MethodDelegate _mainEvent;

    public delegate void MethodDelegate (Object sender, EventArgs e);

    private bool _stop = false;

    private short _ms = 100;
    public short PollingInterval { get { return _ms; }
        set
        {
            _ms = value;
        }
    }

    public Orchestrator()
    {
        _mainThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(_execute));
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _stop = false;
        _mainThread.Start();
    }
    public void Stop()
    {
        _stop = true;
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _mainEvent = null;
    }
    public void Push(MethodDelegate method)
    {
        _mainEvent += method;
    }
    public void Pop(MethodDelegate method)
    {
        _mainEvent -= method;
    }
    private void _execute()
    {
        while(!_stop)
        { 
            if (_mainEvent != null)
                try
                { 
                    _mainEvent(this, new EventArgs());
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                }

            Thread.Sleep(_ms);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You would be much better off using a [`Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to drive this, rather than creating your own thread to do it.

Comment: You don't need to define MethodDelegate. There is already an EventHandler https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @kevin yeah, that is absolutely true...forgot about that

Answer (score 0):

That's basically fine. You need to make `_stop` `volatile`. In C# the event accessor methods are thread-safe so that works fine.

The exception handling is very questionable. Do you really want to spam errors to the console? Define an event `OnError` and report errors to the consumer of your class.

You could use a timer or `await Task.Delay` to save a thread. This would make sense if there are a lot of such class instances at the same time. If there is just one this is likely not worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You're right of course about declaring _stop as volatile. About the error handling you're also right on that of course, but the code I submitted is actually simplified for the sake of conciseness

Answer (score 0):

You have a race condition which could cause a NullReferenceException, in:

```
    while(!_stop)
    { 
        if (_mainEvent != null)
            try
            { 
                _mainEvent(this, new EventArgs());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }

        Thread.Sleep(_ms);
    }
```

Some other thread could unsubscribe from the event or call `Clear()` inbetween  `if (_mainEvent != null)` and the call of `_mainEvent`.

To avoid this, you should copy `_mainEvent` into a local variable and check that against null, and use that instead:

```
    var mainEvent = _mainEvent;
    if (mainEvent != null)
        try
        { 
            mainEvent(this, new EventArgs());
```

In any case, I think you should be using a Timer for this rather than rolling-your-own.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. You're right about the race condition. Wouldn't it also be a solution if i simply create an object like var lockevent = new object(); and then use the statement lock(lockEvent)){...} (or use the Monitor.TryEnter() / Monitor.Exit() pattern) for the code which ivokes the event? Also, why do you think that I would be better off using a Timer? What are the advantages of doing so in this scenario?

Comment: A timer would require additional care because multiple ticks can come in concurrently and ticks can come forever even after disabling the timer.